# Add extra output to existing Chainer network

Tags: python, chainer

Let's say I create a simple fully connected network:

```
import chainer
import chainer.functions as F
import chainer.links as L
from chainer import Sequential

model = Sequential(
    L.Linear(n_in, n_hidden),
    F.relu,
    L.Linear(n_hidden, n_hidden),
    F.relu,
    L.Linear(n_hidden, n_out)
)

# Compute the forward pass
y = model(x)
```

I want to train this model with `n_out` outputs, then, after it is trained, to **add extra outputs** before fine-tuning the network.

I have found ways to remove the last layer in order to retrain a new last layer, however this is not what I want: I want to **keep the weights of the existing outputs**. The weights of the new outputs would be initialized randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about introducing an additional linear layer `L.Linear(n_hidden, n_extra_out)` (without removing any of the existing ones) where `n_extra_out` is the number of additional outputs. You can then extract the output from the last `F.relu` (you might want to consider replacing the `Sequential` object with an instance of a `chainer.Chain` implementation for this, similar to this example https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/examples/mnist/train_mnist.py#L16) and pass it as inputs to both your pretrained last linear layer as well as this new layer. The two outputs can then be concatenated using `F.concat`.